# How to use openssl to get self signed certificate and validate it in a URLSession authentication challenge

Tags: swift, url, openssl, ssl-certificate, urlsession

I am trying to create and validate a self-signed certificate in an URLSession but I am struggling to combine it all and pass the authentication. I always get a `SectrustResultType.recoverableTrustFailure`

I don't know if I create the certificate incorrectly with openssl or if I do not authenticate it properly with the SecTrust functions.

I issue the certificate with the following commands:

```
SUBJ="/C=US/O=RemoteStash/OU=server/CN=localhost"
SUBJCA="/C=US/O=RemoteStashCA/OU=CA/CN=authority"

# Create the certificate authority
openssl genrsa -des3 -out remotestash-ca.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key remotestash-ca.key -sha256 -days 3650 -out remotestash-ca.pem -subj $SUBJCA

# Create new key/cert for the server
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout remotestash-key.pem -out remotestash-cert.pem -subj $SUBJ

# Create the signature request
openssl req -new -key remotestash-key.pem -out remotestash-cert.csr -subj $SUBJ

# Sign the request
openssl x509 -req -in remotestash-cert.csr -CA remotestash-ca.pem -CAkey remotestash-ca.key -CAcreateserial -out remotestash-cert-signed.pem -days 3650 -sha256

# Convert to der format (So i can compare the data of the certificate later)
openssl x509 -outform der -in remotestash-ca.pem -out remotestash-ca.der
openssl x509 -outform der -in remotestash-cert-signed.pem -out remotestash-cert-signed.der
```

In the server I use `remotestash-cert-signed.pem` and `remotestash-key.pem`

Now in the iPhone app code, I implement the challenge as below:

```swift
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        // Try to create a serverTrust with the certificate added
        if let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust,
           let certPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "remotestash-ca", ofType: "der"),
           let certData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: certPath)),
           let cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certData as CFData),
           let remoteCert = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, 0) {
            SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, [cert] as CFArray)
            SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly(trust, false)
            
            let remoteCertData = SecCertificateCopyData(remoteCert) as Data
                
            // check if pass trust
            var trustResult : SecTrustResultType = SecTrustResultType.invalid
            SecTrustGetTrustResult(trust, &trustResult)
            if trustResult == .unspecified || trustResult == .proceed {
                completionHandler(.useCredential,URLCredential(trust: trust))
            }else{
                completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge,nil)
            }
        }else{
            completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge,nil)
        }
    }
```

I could verify that the certificate used by the server is correct by adding inside the challenge code above the following check that proves the server used remotestash-cert-signed

```swift
                if let certPath2 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "remotestash-cert-signed", ofType: "der"),
                   let certData2 = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: certPath2)) {
                    if remoteCertData == certData2 {
                        print( "equal" )
                    }else{
                        print( "not equal" )
                    }
                }
```

But the result of `SecTrustGetTrustResult` is always `SecTrustResultType.recoverableTrustFailure`

Any idea where is my mistake or how to get the trust result to succeed?

Comment: Have you trusted your certificate on the device?

Comment: No, this is what I am trying to avoid, I am trying to valid against a certificate CA I provide. But I just figured out what the issue is, or at least how to make it work, will post answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out how to make it work.

It does not work because the trust object `challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust` has a SSL `SecPolicy`, which make sense, but here as it gets validated on the local network with IP address that policy check fails with the hostname not matching.

So if I create a trust object with SecPolicy of type BasicX509, then it validates only that the server certificate was signed by the desired CA certificate and it works.

Here is the code that worked:

```swift
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        // for logging purpose only
        let url  = task.currentRequest?.url ?? URL(fileURLWithPath: "")
        
        // Extract the certificate to validate from the challenge and load our known CA certificate
        guard
            let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust,
            let caCertPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "remotestash-ca", ofType: "der"),
            let caCertData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: caCertPath)),
            let caCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, caCertData as CFData),
            let remoteCert = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, 0)
        else {
            logger.error("\(url) server trust failed to setup manual authentication")
            completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge,nil)
            return
        }
            
        // Create a trust object to valid the remote certificate against our certificate authority
        let policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509()
        var optionalTrust : SecTrust?
        var trustResult : SecTrustResultType = SecTrustResultType.invalid
        guard
            SecTrustCreateWithCertificates([remoteCert] as CFArray, policy, &optionalTrust) == errSecSuccess,
            let caTrust = optionalTrust,
            SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(caTrust, [caCert] as CFArray) == errSecSuccess,
            SecTrustGetTrustResult(caTrust, &trustResult) == errSecSuccess
        else{
            logger.error("\(url) server trust failed to execute authentication")
            completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge,nil)
            return
        }
        
        switch trustResult{
        case .unspecified,.proceed:
            logger.info("\(url) remotestash certificate valid")
            completionHandler(.useCredential,URLCredential(trust: trust))
        default:
            logger.info("\(url) invalid certificate")
            completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge,nil)
        }
    }
```